# Groovy: Problem when writing string parameter to file

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I've a jenkinsfile containing a string parameter:

```
 parameters {
    string (
        name: 'ParPattern',
        defaultValue: "{'XY1*'}"
    )
}
```

Later on, I'm writing this to a text file:

```
def Simulation(ParPattern) {
    writeFile (
        file: 'myfile.txt',
        text: """                    
                    FunctionCall(${ParPattern});
            """.stripIndent()
    )
```

When running the job with parameter value `{'XY9?7','XY9?8','XY9?9','XY9?​0','XY9*0'}` I expect to get a `myFile.txt` containing

```
FunctionCall({'XY9?7','XY9?8','XY9?9','XY9?​0','XY9*0'})
```

Instead I get

```
FunctionCall({'XY9?7','XY9?8','XY9?9','XY9??0','XY9*0'})
```

Why does the second question mark shows up in `XY9?0`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems there was an extra `.` that came up when I copied the default values.

[image]

I removed the extra `.` and added in the default value, then it gave the value.

Comment: When pasting the argument to notepad++ while showing all special chars, I don't see that. What exactly did you do?

Comment: Just paste it in Jenkinsfile Pipeline script and you will see the ``.``

Comment: Thanks a lot. Neither in vscode nor in notepad++ this special char is visible, but - as shown in your answer - in jenkins' pipeline editor.